# Dbfit: Login failed for user 'dev\abc'. Client connectionId:a12f7cab

Tags: dbfit

I am trying to connect **sqlserver** from `dbfit`, and getting below error:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user
>   'DEV\abc'. ClientConnectionId:a12f7cab-7261-4fa7-8064-ea355f03f883    at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:254)
>     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:84)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:2908)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:2234)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:41)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:2220)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1326)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:991)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
>     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)     at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)  at
>   dbfit.api.AbstractDbEnvironment.connect(AbstractDbEnvironment.java:51)
>     at
>   dbfit.environment.SqlServerEnvironment.connect(SqlServerEnvironment.java:53)
>     at
>   dbfit.api.AbstractDbEnvironment.connect(AbstractDbEnvironment.java:78)
>     at
>   dbfit.fixture.DatabaseEnvironment.connect(DatabaseEnvironment.java:52)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   fitlibrary.closure.MethodClosure.invoke(MethodClosure.java:35)    at
>   fitlibrary.closure.MethodClosure.invokeTyped(MethodClosure.java:28)
>     at
>   fitlibrary.closure.CalledMethodTarget.invokeTyped(CalledMethodTarget.java:77)
>     at
>   fitlibrary.closure.CalledMethodTarget.invokeTyped(CalledMethodTarget.java:95)
>     at
>   fitlibrary.closure.CalledMethodTarget.invokeAndWrap(CalledMethodTarget.java:358)
>     at
>   fitlibrary.traverse.workflow.caller.ActionCaller.run(ActionCaller.java:37)
>     at
>   fitlibrary.traverse.workflow.DoTraverseInterpreter.interpretRow(DoTraverseInterpreter.java:176)
>     at
>   fitlibrary.traverse.workflow.DoTraverseInterpreter.interpretAfterFirstRow(DoTraverseInterpreter.java:66)
>     at
>   fitlibrary.traverse.workflow.DoTraverseInterpreter.interpretInFlow(DoTraverseInterpreter.java:151)
>     at fitlibrary.DoFixture.interpretAfterFirstRow(DoFixture.java:47)   at
>   fitlibrary.FitLibraryFixture.doTable(FitLibraryFixture.java:83)   at
>   dbfit.fixture.DatabaseEnvironment.doTable(DatabaseEnvironment.java:22)
>     at fit.Fixture.interpretFollowingTables(Fixture.java:121)   at
>   fit.Fixture.interpretTables(Fixture.java:107)     at
>   fit.Fixture.doTables(Fixture.java:81)     at
>   fit.FitServer.process(FitServer.java:81)  at
>   fit.FitServer.run(FitServer.java:56)  at
>   fit.FitServer.main(FitServer.java:41)

Is anyone facing similar issue?

Appreciate your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I missed below step:

(http://dbfit.github.io/dbfit/docs/database-specific-information.html#microsoft-sql-server)
Microsoft SQL Server

Deploying the JDBC Driver

```
Download MS SQL Server JDBC driver from their site (It is not open source and cannot be distributed with DbFit.)
Deploy sqljdbc4.jar in DbFit’s lib folder - the same folder as dbfit-XXX.jar.
Deploy auth\x86\sqljdbc_auth.dll in %programfiles(x86)%\Java\jre7\bin folder to allow integrated windows authentication
```

Then use connetion as

!|DatabaseEnvironment|sqlserver|
|Connect|jdbc:sqlserver://myhost;integratedSecurity=true|

and it worked.